# I sent "ballistic" in official meeting and I am from the middle east!

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

First I am not a native english speaker

Today there was a meeting with the tech hardware department where i work

One of that department suggested that I should have another meeting with the title of "implementation ballistics"!!

I checked the meaning of the word ballistics as the only meaning I know is linked to ballistics missiles!

and it was as I knew just linked to missiles

I checked with one of my colleagues and she said she heard "ballistics"

so "ballistics" it is.

I sent the meeting invitation to all titled "implementation ballistics"

1 minute later my manager sent me, do we need guns?!

and asked me to change the meeting title.

Which I did.

My question, Is there any other meaning to "ballistics" that can be related to technical hardware or any other meaning that we did not get?

Considering I am from the middle east, this meeting title could cause me lots of trouble

so an answer will be appreciated

Comment: My guess is that the originally spoken/intended word was "logistics"—not "ballistics."

Comment: Ballistic means "moving under the force of gravity", and applies to any projectile, not only to missiles.  But I agree, do not use it as the title for a meeting.

Comment: @SvenYargs yea, it could be logistics

Comment: Are you intending to use catapults or trebuchets to shoot containers full of documents from one site to another? If you could guarantee accuracy it might be an answer to slow, insecure internet connections. I jest but you might be onto something.

Comment: "I sent ballistic" is much less serious than "I went ballistic".